# bottomnavigation programatic navigation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have two pages 0 and 1. there is a button in page 0 that opens a modal which has a button that should close the modal and navigate to page two. I tried to achieve this by binding `:selectedindex` but it doesn't work. Any thoughts? Here is the [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Cr5A99&v=22)

If you click on 1, then press the button `go to 0` then `show modal`, then `go to 1`, it will take you to page 1.

If you click on 0, then `show modal`, then `go to 1`, it will take you to page 0.

P.S.

If I commit my mutation with a delay the problem is solved but the truth is that would be a bad UX and the user would see page 0 first and then quickly switch to page 1 but I would like the user to immediately only see page 1 when they close the modal.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.$store.commit(
        "SET_ACTIVE_PAGE_INDEX", 1);
}, 10);
```

**In case playground disappears, here are the codes:**

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import Vuex from './vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: { activePageIndex: 2 },
    mutations: {
        SET_ACTIVE_PAGE_INDEX(state, v) {
            state.activePageIndex = v;
        },
    },
});
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue'
import App from './components/App'
import store from './store'

Vue.prototype.$store = store;
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(App)])
}).$start()
```

**components/App.vue**

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <BottomNavigation :selectedIndex="$store.state.activePageIndex">
            <TabStrip>
                <TabStripItem>
                    <label text="0" />
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem>
                    <label text="1" />
                </TabStripItem>
            </TabStrip>

            <TabContentItem>
                <button text="show modal" @tap="showModal" />
            </TabContentItem>
            <TabContentItem>
                <button text="go to 0"
                    @tap="$store.commit('SET_ACTIVE_PAGE_INDEX', 0)" />
            </TabContentItem>
        </BottomNavigation>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import Modal from "./Modal";

    export default {
        methods: {
            showModal() {
                this.$showModal(Modal, {
                    fullscreen: true,
                    transition: {
                        name: "slideTop"
                    },
                    clearHistory: true
                }).then(is_to_1 => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.$store.commit(
                            "SET_ACTIVE_PAGE_INDEX", 1);
                    }, 10);
                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    TabContentItem>* {
        font-size: 30;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

**components/Modal.vue**

```
<template>
    <StackLayout>|
        <button text="go to 1" @tap="$modal.close(true)" />
    </StackLayout>|
</template>

<script>
    export default {};
</script>

<style scoped>
    button {
        font-size: 30;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please double check the Playground link, it says invalid.

Comment: I believe I can see the issue in Playground itself, is it the tab doesn't switch to 1st index after closing the modal? Though it's not constantly reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj yes, exactly.

Comment: @Manoj by the way, any idea why the modal's button text does not show up?

Comment: I guess that's the padding you have given.

Comment: Reg your OP, I think it's an issue with Android, possibly a bug in framework. It doesn't change the tab when it's not visible. There is few milliseconds delay sometimes between hiding the modal and showing tab view, there it fails to update selected index. Try using a timeout of 500ms.

Comment: @Manoj I experience this on IOS too, don't you?

Comment: I reviewed only the Android code, I will check iOS once. But did the timeout solve the issue?

Comment: @Manoj I already updated my answer a long time ago and said that the timeout solves it, and I also explained that It brings bad UX.